# Is there any way how to restrict access/buy at Azure Marketplace?

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

is there any way how to restrict access or buy permissions at Azure Marketplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a policy like the one below to restrict compute resources from a specific publisher -

```
        {
          "policyRule": {
            "if": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                  "match": "[parameters('NotAllowedImage')]"
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "effect": "Deny"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "NotAllowedImage": {
              "type": "String",
              "metadata": {
                "displayName": "Not Allowed  Image",
                "description": "Not Allowed Image for Virtual Machine/Compute"
              }
            }
          },
          "metadata": {
            "category": "Compute"
          }
        }
```

When you assign this image to a subscription or a resource group then at the time you will be asked to enter a value for the image name you would like to restrict , please enter "checkpoint" as your publisher name as this is the one you want to restrict. Save the assignment.

Now once you create a vm/compute resource from "checkpoint" this would fail the validation step as the policy would not allow to create such vm/compute resource.

The Category of the check point resources I see in market place is compute only. [image: Screenshot market place resource]

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

We might not have restrictions on what we can choose from market place but we can utilize azure policy for certain resource regulation/compliance.

These policies would help enforce different rules over your resources(VM'S , VM-SKU , Network , Storage etc.). If you need resources  created to stay compliant with your company  standards/service level agreements.

Whenever we create resource which has policy tied to it these are evaluated and scanned for compliance with that policy.

More info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/azure-policy-introduction

Comment: I am not really sure, if got that answer for which i was looking for, but... I am i correct, if i say there isnt a way how to restrict what i can see on market. But There is a way by Policy how to restrict recources for Market per every Recourse groupe?

Comment: Well not choosing resources from  marketplace , but resources(VM , Storage , Netowork etc) you create inside azure itself. Here is more information on azure policies - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-policy/

Comment: Thank you for your patience, i have one last question. So if i can ask you, is there any documentation for Allowed resource types? Because there is a list with about 500 of them and just by their name in Azure we cant be really sure what it is doing. Or if there is easier way, how to do it I will be very glad.

Example of resource type which we dont know what its doing: "Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering/agreements"

Again i thank you so much

Comment: I understand the list you are seeing is list of providers which might not make lot of sense initially .We can list the provider namespaces  to resource types mapping using the powershell  cmdlet -  get-azurermresourceprovider| select-object providernamespace,resourcetypes.  Of course we need to login to your subscription before running this cmdlet using Login-AzurermAccount.

Comment: I've tried your command, and that said to me list of resource types, but we dont know how to use it to restrict specific resource by policy :(

Comment: Hey, do you know how to restrict Check Point Security service? I have no idea how to recognize it. VMs are easy, since there is a "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" resource type, but as for Security services, I have no idea which resource type to use in the script. The fact that I have never used JSON before and I am not a programmer might not help. Thank you for your help.